# set php variable on radio box without submitting the form

Tags: php, javascript, list, variables, radio-button

i have a set of radio boxes, and a select list. The radio boxes represents the objects, and the select list represents the number of pieces for every object (to be bought).
i want to synchronise the stock with the select list. meaning that, if i choose the first product and i have only 6 products in the stock, i want the maximum value in the select list to be 6. if i choose the second and i have only 2 products in the stock, i want the maximum to be 2.

How do i synchronise the select list with the radio boxes?

thanks!

Comment: You should use JavaScript for this.

Comment: This is tagged PHP, but you're going to need some javascript to do this...

Comment: Chris is right, I have also edited the tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As PHP is a dependent server-side script, this would be very hard to do, if not impossible with just PHP. I see two options:

1. Use a bit of Javascript to refresh the page whenever a form element is updated, and use those corresponding values in a PHP script to update the form with the new values.
2. Use JQuery or AJAX to request a PHP script that will do the same thing. Same in concept, but wont refresh the page each time.

Comment: Using an AJAX call on every product click is a bit overkilling ;-) You could already output the stock inside a formatted class (like "stock-6") on each radio and use it when clicked to adapt the select options.

Comment: Essentially, pull all the data you need in PHP and send that to JQuery or AJAX, then query that class for data whenever the form is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write javascript that loads with the page, that will limit the amounts for those fields.  The javascript would be created in your php and inserted into the page on load.